# How to make help open local help automatically instead of asking to choose each time?

Tags: documentation

Since I am asking today about new changes in version 12 display, I might as well ask about this change.

Each time, when asking for help using `?Command`, I now find I have to click one extra time compared to version 11.3, in order to choose `local` help instead of the `web` help.  Since I always want to look at the local help, this extra click each time is a little annoying.  Here is an example

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to 11.3

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One might argue than one extra click is not a big deal. But doing this 50 times per day, 30 times per month, 12 months per year, this becomes 18,000 extra clicks per year.

Is there an option in option inspector to make it automatically open local help for those of us who want this choice all the time?  (I did not know what to search for) Or to make help display the lower panel at the same time, so one can click on `local` directly?

Comment: You may already know about this, but my favorite way to open a doc page is to hit F1 when the cursor is within a symbol. If you are counting clicks that may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out, but just click here instead:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think someone at WRI should do a User Interface ergonomics survey before making such changes as it is a little not consistent with how UI behaved before.

Comment: I know, I thought that (i) was just a graphic denoting that it's an information box.